# Search view disappears when 'search' button on the soft keyboard is clicked

Tags: android

I have a search view on my menu. When I search for something and then click on the 'search' button on the phone's keyboard, the search view disappears.

I have tried implementing `setOnKeyListener` but it doesn't seem to work. Help would be highly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```js
searchView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {    
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            switch (keyCode){
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH:
                    String search_text = searchView.getQuery().toString().trim();
                    int s = 0;
                    if (adapter != null) {
                        s = adapter.ManageProducts_filter(search_text, newmSectionList);
                    }
                    if (s != 0) {
                        searchView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    return true;
             }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Have also implemented setOnQueryTextListener:

```js
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        String text = query.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
        int size = 0;
        if (adapter != null) {
            size = adapter.ManageProducts_filter(text, newmSectionList);
        }
        if (size != 0) {
            searchView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        if (adapter != null) {
            adapter.ManageProducts_filter(newText, newmSectionList);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

Comment: Why did you use a `switch` in the first block of code? Are you planning on adding other keys in the future? If not, a simple `if` will suffice.

Comment: I had intended to add additional keys initially but now I only have to work with the 'Search' key. I had written an if condition as well but the setOnKeyListener method doesn't get called. I was wondering if I was using the wrong method? Maybe some other method should be used?

Comment: Did you try to put the listener on the textbox instead of on the view?